# Click event not firing in angular universal

Tags: angular, click, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, mouseclick-event

I have converted my angular project into angular universal. The node server is working and displaying the project at localhost:4000 but the click event that i have applied on my button which is calling a function in the .ts file has stopped working somehow.
Any idea how to fix this issue.

Comment: Can you provide more info? Like code plz

Comment: Hey! It's a company project can't share.. but i can share the package.json and server.ts file if that helps you .

Answer (score -1):

The click handler will be executed on server side and client side. To ensure that the click event only will be executed in the client (for example show a menu / div / popup etc), you must implement `isPlatformBrowser`

Have a look at the code here:

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit, PLATFORM_ID } from "@angular/core";
import { isPlatformBrowser }
    from '@angular/common';

@Component({
    selector: "app-navigation",
    templateUrl: "navigation.component.html"
})
export class NavigationComponent implements OnInit {


    public isNavAsideActive: boolean;

    constructor(
        @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private readonly _platformId: Object
    ) {
        this.isNavAsideActive = false;
    }

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        if (isPlatformBrowser(this._platformId) === true) {
            console.debug("isPlatformBrowser");
        }
    }

    public onAsideButtonClick(): void {
        if (isPlatformBrowser(this._platformId)) {
            console.debug("this.isNavAsideActive", this.isNavAsideActive);
            this.isNavAsideActive = !this.isNavAsideActive;
        }
    }
}
```